# Drawing something in CanvasView using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, cgcontext

I am wondering if it's possible drawing something with CGContext and CanvasView in SwiftUI instead using UIKit, like this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2NTCmEsdSE).

Do I have to integrate UIKit for doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to integrate UIKit for doing that?

SwiftUI does not provide access to `CGContext`, consider it as a descriptive model, so yes, you have to integrate UIKit via `UIViewRepresentable` for doing that.

Comment: Thanks! it means that for some things (e.g. ARKit) it's not possibile to not use UIKit?

Comment: @Edoardo, SwiftUI does not replace UIKit, it complements it.

Comment: @Edoardo see SwiftUI.Path